# SQL Query with 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this Classic ASP application running with SQL Server. I use the following query:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 30 r.RMANumber, r.CompanyName, r.ContactName, r.Country, r.Phone, r.IssuanceDate, r.DateReceived, r.CreatedBy " & _
      "FROM rma r " & _
      "WHERE r.IssuanceDate >= '" & startDate & "' AND r.IssuanceDate <= '" & DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(endDate)) & "' AND r.RMAClosed = 'No' " & _
      "ORDER BY IssuanceDate DESC"
```

I'd like to add an `INNER JOIN` to it but the `INNER JOIN` would look in the different database. Can I do this:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 30 r.RMANumber, r.CompanyName, r.ContactName, r.Country, r.Phone, r.IssuanceDate, r.DateReceived, r.CreatedBy " & _
     "FROM [database1].[dbo].[rma] r " & _
     "INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[users] u " & _
```

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Try first, ask questions later.

Comment: @Brasciole: Yes, you can. Take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) , give it a shot and come back with what you tried and any questions you have.

Comment: Yes, as long as the databases are in the same Server...

Answer (score 1):

If your other database is in another server. Put the IP address of the server as shown below:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 30 r.RMANumber, r.CompanyName, r.ContactName, r.Country, r.Phone, r.IssuanceDate, r.DateReceived, r.CreatedBy " & _
      "FROM [database1].[dbo].[rma] r " & _
      "INNER JOIN [ip address of other server here].[database2].[dbo].[users] u " & _
```

Note: 
Be sure you're connected and have an access to that server to where your other    database resides.